# Superclass/Interface providing TextAlignment and FontFamily properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set properties of several different WPF RichTextBox controls, like List, ListItem, Paragraph. The properties I want to set are, for example, FontFamily and TextAlignment.

I want to do this as generic as possible, so I have one setter for TextAlignment, one setter for FontFamily, and so on, but I cannot find out the common superclass providing all these properties.

Can you tell me what superclass I am looking for, and, if possible, how to find out what superclass provides different properties in general?

**Edit:** More detailed explanation of the case:
FontFamily is inherited from TextElement, in both Paragraph and ListItem
TextAdjust is inherited from Block in apparently every class but ListItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override metadata for a given UIElement.

For example, if you want to set the default FontSize of all FrameworkElements:

```
System.Windows.Documents
              .TextElement
              .FontSizeProperty
              .OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(5));
```

UIElement/FrameworkElement is as generic as it gets, if you want to apply those defaults to only a few types you need to repeat that line for every type you want.

Answer (score 0):

The common base class that holds all the `Font...` properties is [TextElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.aspx), whereas `TextAlignment` is a property of [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.listitem_properties).

You can easily find this out by yourself when you browse the MSDN pages. There is a tree view on the left that shows Constructors, Fields, Methods, Properties and Events of a class. If you click one of these items it shows a list of items that are defined in that class.

Comment: Well, I can have a "TextAlignment" when using Paragraph, Paragraph is of Supertype Block. As I can have a ListItem as well as a Paragraph, apparently it's not the same superclass that provides these properties (apparently for ListItem.TextAlignment there is no Superclass, while there is a superclass for all other instances of TextAlignment)

Comment: I was just also thinking of the approach suggested by @m0sa. In general, you could set any dependency property on a dependency object, but it won't always be effective. However, with a bit of luck `ListItem.TextAlignment` and `Block.TextAlignment` are backed by the same DependencyProperty registration, e.g. by [AddOwner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597483).

Answer (score 0):

All the properties you are trying to set are dependency properties. You can use the [DependencyObject.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx) method, e.g.:

```
DependencyObject x;
x.SetValue(Block.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Justify);
```

It's just a matter of finding the correct dependency property descriptions then.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I have to, in the case I put up for example, write two lines for TextAlingment only?

`x.SetValue(Block.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Justify);
x.SetValue(ListItem.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Justify); `

Comment: Obiously you would have to visit the entire tree structure of your text and apply the setting to each dependencyobject instance in the tree..